# htaccess mod rewrite changes http://www to http:/www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to replace calls like this:

`www.mysite.com/sub/file.php?param1=x&param2=http://www.someurl.com`

with:

`www.mysite.com/sub/param1/param2`

Param 1 is an integer number Param 2 is a url

I wrote this rewrite rule in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/sub\/
RewriteRule sub\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)$  sub\/file.php?param1=$2&param2=$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately param2 (the URL) starts with `http:/www.someurl.com` instead of `http://www.someurl.com` (note the single slash).

Any idea what causes it? When I call the same file with same parameters in the format `www.mysite.com/sub/file.php?param1=x&param2=http://www.someurl.com` , param2 does appear OK so it must be something with the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grab the value from *THE_REQUEST*:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /sub/[0-9]+/([^?\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^sub/([0-9]+)/  sub/file.php?param1=$1&param2=%1 [L]
```